# Loading user language after user login in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, localization, multilingual

I know that I should load the default language in `application/config/autoload.php`.

But I want that user's favorite language to load after he just logs in.

How can I load a `language` based on `session`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should load the specific language of the user initially within `__construct()` function like this: (Consider `payment` class as an example)

```
class payment extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->lang->load('general', $this->session->userdata('user_language'));
        $this->lang->load('payment', $this->session->userdata('user_language'));

    }

    // Remaining methods...

}
```